# Смена цвета скроллбара при скролле

Tags: css, css3, прокрутка, scrollbar

Всем привет! Кастомизирую скроллбар. Необходимо, чтобы при скролле полоска скроллбара меняла цвет.
Если использовать этот код: `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background: black;}`, то при наведение на полоску скроллбара меняется ее цвет на черный. Нужно то же самое, только при непосредственно скролле мышью.

Comment: css то не умеет такую штуку - надо уже язык программирования который знает что такое скролл

Comment: Хорошо, тогда, как реализовать это в js?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/177399/ почитайте

Comment: а вообще есть целые плагины которые занимаются полосой прокрутки - есть даже самый лучший

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!